# What is the error in this example of training a SVM model

Tags: warning-messages, machine-learning

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 35}, {400, 200}];

trset = Association[{"class1" -> data[[1 ;; 100]], "class2" -> data[[101 ;; 200]]}];

valset = Association[{"class1" -> data[[201 ;; 250]], "class2" -> data[[201 ;; 250]]}];

Classify[trset, ValidationSet -> valset, Method -> "SupportVectorMachine"]
```

I get this error:

```
"Part::partd: Part specification 0.[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>

Part::partd: Part specification 0.[[2,1]] is longer than depth of object. >>"
```

Here this example with MNIST dataset work correctly,!?!

```
totalSet = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "MNIST"}, "Data"];

{trainingSet, validationSet,testSet} = {#[[;; 400]], #[[401 ;; 550]], #[[551 ;; 700]]} &RandomSample[totalSet]];

c = Classify[trainingSet, ValidationSet -> validationSet, Method ->"SupportVectorMachine"];
```

Comment: The error occurs when you include `Method -> "SupportVectorMachine"`. as an option to your call to `Classify`. Perhaps that gives you a way forward.

Comment: @march, I think that is a bug in mathematica!

Comment: Perhaps trying to generate a classifier on a completely random data set may not be the best way to test a classification method. I think you are running into a corner case of some kind, and whether or not this is relevant to a real application is hard to say. As you showed yourself, the problem doesn't appear with a reasonable data set.

Comment: @MarcoB, I did not think! The dataset is numerical and randomly, I can understand if I have a problem of training, a problem of overfitting or any other problem about the quality of the result. But ,here we have a bug in the code, so, may the structure of the input is not good despite of I used a the third Association [] as mentioned in the documentation

Comment: @Developer2000 I think you should report this problem to Wolfram Support then, and see what they think. Let us know as well!

Comment: @MarcoB, OK, I am writing for them.

Comment: @MarcoB I receive the confirmation of technical support about this bug.

Comment: @Developer2000 Thank you for letting us know. Would you please include that information in your question (perhaps the support case numbers as well), together with any further information that support may have provided?