# An example showcasing ValidationSet's utility

Tags: machine-learning

Validation sets form a fundamental part of machine learning by minimising overfitting but is there a nice example showcasing this effect when using `Predict`/`Classify`?

Comment: The documentation shows how setting the option `ValidationSet` can lead to *different* models but not necessarily more *accurate* ones. By default, some (undocumented) cross-validation is performed so the advantages of any explicit user-setting would seem to only be demonstrable in comparison to this default action (but still sought here) and not in comparison to *no* validation at all).

Answer (score 1):

This is a negative answer in the sense of suggesting where *not* to look - the built-in datasets. The following evaluation is readily described: (definitions follow)

```
ValidationEffect[{UCILetterMLData, 1}, {0.5, 0.25, 0.25}, 10]
```

> <|"Frac" -> {1, 20000}, "noVS" -> {0.9624, 0.919216, 0.928214},
>   "yesVS" -> {0.9624, 0.919216, 0.928214}, "diffs" -> {0., 0}|>

This shows that if you take all 20 000 classifications in the `UCILetter` dataset and partition into training/validation/test sets according to the proportions `{0.5, 0.25, 0.25}` then (with random seed 10) the resulting model, `noVS`, *without* the validation set (i.e. trained only on the training set) has corresponding accuracies `{0.9624, 0.919216, 0.928214}` on the training/validation/test sets whereas the model, `yesVS`, trained *with* the validation set has corresponding accuracies `{0.9624, 0.919216, 0.928214}`. These accuracies are identical suggesting the same model is being generated as confirmed by diffs of `(0,0)` - the proportion and raw number of *different* outputs when the respective models act on elements of the test set.

Now, changing the partition proportions does seem to result in a setting of `ValidationSet` having an effect

```
ValidationEffect[{UCILetterMLData, 1}, {0.8, 0.1, 0.1}, 10]
```

> <|"Frac" -> {1, 20000}, "noVS" -> {0.958563, 0.936532, 0.936532}, 
>   "yesVS" -> {0.971688, 0.937531, 0.942029},   "diffs" ->
>   {0.0414793, 83}|>

but not a significant one with both models disagreeing only 0.04 of the time with both having an accuracy of ~0.94 on the test set.

This effect seems to be linked to the dataset's size. Taking `0.1` of the largest built-in dataset, `MNISTMLData` shows `ValidationSet` having no impact (even with `7000` datapoints)

```
ValidationEffect[{MNISTMLData, .1}, {40000/70000, 15000/70000, 15000/
  70000}, 21]
```

> <|"Frac" -> {0.1, 7000}, "noVS" -> {0.9265, 0.897402, 0.897402},
>   "yesVS" -> {0.9265, 0.897402, 0.897402}, "diffs" -> {0., 0}|>

but even when a `ValidationSet` *does* have an effect, the new model is not significantly more accurate (warning -  this takes a while, >20 min, to evaluate)

```
ValidationEffect[{MNISTMLData, 1}, {40000/70000, 15000/70000, 15000/
  70000}, 21]
```

> <|"Frac" -> {1, 70000}, "noVS" -> {0.961025, 0.954403, 0.949337}, 
>   "yesVS" -> {0.952075, 0.950137, 0.94367},   "diffs" -> {0.0198653,
>   298}|>

Note the fraction proportions are from another answer in partly explaining its exhibited anomalies.

This behaviour seems unchanged for other random seeds (unaccountably though, often even with the *same* random seed negligibly different models are produced?) nor does it seem to change for other inbuilt datasets as run on `{BostonHomesMLData,FisherIrisMLData, MNISTMLData,MovieReviewMLData,MushroomMLData,SatelliteMLData,TitanicMLData,UCILetterMLData,WineQualityMLData}`.

The upshot seems to be that, at least for the inbuilt datasets, setting `ValidationSet` either has no effect either in terms of generating new models or else in terms of new models that surpass those generated by default - via the built-in (cross) validation.

Definitions:

```
oClassifierMeasurements[model_] := 
  Function[set, ClassifierMeasurements[model, set, "Accuracy"]];

oDrop[specs__] := Function[ls, Drop[ls, specs]];

oPartition[specs__] := Function[ls, Partition[ls, specs]];

ProportionalSplit[ls_, split_List /; Total@split == 1] := Let[
   n = Length@ls,
   parts = (split // oDrop@-1 // Accumulate) // (Map[Round[n*#] &]) //
        Prepend@0 // Append@n // oPartition[2, 1],
   ls // Query[Span @@@ parts]];

ProportionalSplit[split_] := 
  Function[ls, ProportionalSplit[ls, split]];

ValidationEffect[{dataSet_, frac_}, split_List, seed_: 10] := Let[
   n = (frac*Length@dataSet // Ceiling),
   {trainingSet, validationSet, testSet} =
    RandomSample[dataSet, n] // ProportionalSplit@split,
   noVS = (RandomSeed@seed; Classify[trainingSet]),
   yesVS = (RandomSeed@seed; 
     Classify[trainingSet, ValidationSet -> validationSet]),
   testKeys = Keys@testSet,
   diffCount = 
    Count[UnsameQ @@@ (Thread[{noVS@testKeys, yesVS@testKeys}]), True],
    <|
    "Frac" -> {frac, n},
    "noVS_Acc" -> ({trainingSet, validationSet, testSet} // 
       Map@oClassifierMeasurements@noVS),
    "yesVS_Acc" -> ({trainingSet, validationSet, testSet} // 
       Map@oClassifierMeasurements@yesVS),
    "diffs" -> {N@diffCount/(Length@testSet), diffCount}
    |>
   ];

ExampleData["MachineLearning"] // Scan[
   Let[symb = ToExpression[#[[2]] <> "MLData"],
     dummy; symb = ExampleData[#, "Data"]] &];
```